# Need to run Java code in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I created a new google web application project (using eclipse) and noticed the code runs in the .server package.  I have a slot machine game i wrote in java and am trying to implement it into GWT, but the syntax seems to be totally different. (for example, i noticed \n doesn't work)

Here is the code i want to implement - how the heck would i do that?

```
// clear console
static void clearConsole()
{
    for (int i=0; i<25; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}


// actual slot machine algorithm
static void slots()
{

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    char newGame = ' ';

    int chips = 100;
    int bet = 0;


    do{
         System.out.println( "Try your luck on the SLOT MACHINE." +
                 "\nLine up (=^^=) or ))<>(( symbols to win big!\n\n" +
                "You currently have " + chips + " chips.\nHow much do you want to bet? ");



         //check for accidental char input
         try{
             bet = input.nextInt();

         }
         catch(Exception e){

             input.nextLine();
             System.out.println("NOT A VALID NUMBER\nHow much do you want to bet? ");
             bet = input.nextInt();
         }



        if (bet<=chips && bet>0){

            // to add some realism, slot machine will not execute until 'enter' pressed
            // then console cleared
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.println( "\nPress 'enter' to start the slot machine.");
            input.nextLine();
            clearConsole();

            String[] machine = {"(=^^=)", "(=^^=)", "))<>((", " XXXX ", " XXXX ", " :^{) ",
                                  " :^{) ", " (>_<)", " (>_<)", " [-O-]", " [-O-]"}; 
            Random rand = new Random();
            int slot1 = rand.nextInt(11);
            int slot2 = rand.nextInt(11);
            int slot3 = rand.nextInt(11);
            int slot4 = rand.nextInt(11);
            int slot5 = rand.nextInt(11);
            int slot6 = rand.nextInt(11);
            int slot7 = rand.nextInt(11);
            int slot8 = rand.nextInt(11);
            int slot9 = rand.nextInt(11);

            System.out.println( "-----------------------");
            System.out.printf( "%-7s %-7s %-7s %n%n", machine[slot1], machine[slot2], machine[slot3]);
            System.out.printf( "%-7s %-7s %-7s %n%n", machine[slot4], machine[slot5], machine[slot6]);
            System.out.printf( "%-7s %-7s %-7s %n", machine[slot7], machine[slot8], machine[slot9]);
            System.out.println( "-----------------------\n\n\n\n");

            // 3 wild cards
            if (slot4 == 2 && slot5 == 2 && slot6 == 2 ){
                bet = bet*100;
                chips = chips + bet;
                System.out.println( "JACKPOT! ");
            }

            //3 cats (inclusive of wild card)
            else if (   slot4 <3 && slot5 <3 && slot6 <3 ){
                bet = bet*5;
                chips = chips + bet;
                System.out.println( "YOU WIN! ");
            }

            // 3 of any other symbol (inclusive of wild card)
            else if( ((slot4==2 || slot4==3 || slot4==4) && (slot5==2 || slot5==3 || 
                                            slot5==4) && (slot6==2 || slot6==3 || slot6==4))
                    || ((slot4==2 || slot4==5 || slot4==6) && (slot5==2 || slot5==5 || 
                                            slot5==6) && (slot6==2 || slot6==5 || slot6==6))
                    || ((slot4==2 || slot4==7 || slot4==8) && (slot5==2 || slot5==7 || 
                                            slot5==8) && (slot6==2 || slot6==7 || slot6==8))
                    || ((slot4==2 || slot4==9 || slot4==10) && (slot5==2 || slot5==9 || 
                                       slot5==10) && (slot6==2 || slot6==9 || slot6==10)) ){
                bet = bet*3;
                chips = chips + bet;
                System.out.println( "YOU WIN! ");
            }

            // 2 cats
            else if ( slot4<2 && slot5<2 || slot4<2 && slot6<2 || slot5<2 && slot6<2){
                bet = bet*2;
                chips = chips + bet;
                System.out.println( "YOU WIN! ");
            }

            // 1 cat
            else if ( slot4 < 2 || slot5 < 2 || slot6 < 2 ){
                chips = chips + bet;
                System.out.println( "YOU WIN! ");
            }

            // nothing
            else{
                chips = chips - bet;
                System.out.print( "You Lose... ");
            }

            // display current amount of chips
            System.out.println( "You have " + chips + " chips.");


         }else{
            System.out.println( "You do not have enough chips to make that bet!");
         }


        if (chips > 0){
            System.out.println( "\nDo you wanna play this game again? (y/n): ");
            newGame = input.next().charAt(0);
            clearConsole();
        }

    } while (newGame =='y' && chips > 0 );


    input.close();

    System.out.println( "\nGame Over\n\n");
}
```

Comment: GWT is used for creating web applications, your code is for a console application - how do you expect it to work in the browser?

Comment: perhaps start with a GWT tutorial. http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/gettingstarted.html

Answer (score 0):

You could replace System.out.println with putting raw text (not even HTML) into an element with fixed space etc (something like the "pre" element).

I'd suggest you switch to something like Button for "enter", "y"/"n"... and and DoubleBox for the amount they want to bet.

There may be a more general "console" in browser approach but it would be a bit odd?

Maybe best starting with one of the GWT samples and slowly converting to what you want? Quite a bit of bootstrapping to get a GWT app up and running.